# How to bypass the pointless checking array.filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 inputs for filtering `arrProd` (see code bellow). In the FormSubmit function, I firstly check if the value of price.minPrice and price.maxPrice are valid numbers and not empty strings. After these checks there can be only two options: either user writes in and inputs digits or leaves the fields blank. Then I check if the numbers have started, then the array is being filtered. In the filtering loop it is meaningless to check the value several times. How can I do it to check it only once?

```
import React, { Fragment, useCallback, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const arrProd = [
  {
    price: "5.75",
    sold: "100"
  },
  {
    price: "2.36",
    sold: "15"
  },
  {
    price: "5.48",
    sold: "20"
  },
  {
    price: "4.49",
    sold: "200"
  },
  {
    price: "3.15",
    sold: "258"
  },
  {
    price: "9.99",
    sold: "479"
  },
  {
    price: "4.8",
    sold: "147"
  },
  {
    price: "8",
    sold: "951"
  },
  {
    price: "4.27",
    sold: "753"
  },
  {
    price: "2.46",
    sold: "852"
  },
  {
    price: "4.99",
    sold: "742"
  },
  {
    price: "3.49",
    sold: "10"
  },
  {
    price: "2",
    sold: "26"
  },
  {
    price: "3.83",
    sold: "39"
  },
  {
    price: "9.98",
    sold: "47"
  },
  {
    price: "6.77",
    sold: "96"
  }
];

function App() {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState({ maxPrice: "", minPrice: "" });
  const [sold, setSold] = useState("");
  const [processingProd, setProcessingProd] = useState([]);
  const [checkInput, setCheckInput] = useState({
    checkPrice: false,
    checkSold: false
  });

  const PriceMaxMin = useCallback(({ target: { value, name } }) => {
    name === "maxPrice"
      ? setPrice(({ minPrice }) => ({ maxPrice: value, minPrice }))
      : setPrice(({ maxPrice }) => ({ minPrice: value, maxPrice }));
  }, []);
  console.log(processingProd);
  const FormSubmit = event => {
    if (checkInput.checkPrice) setCheckInput({ checkPrice: false });
    const checkPrice =
      price.minPrice === "" && price.minPrice === ""
        ? "initial values"
        : +price.maxPrice >= +price.minPrice &&
          price.minPrice !== "" &&
          !Number.isNaN(+price.maxPrice) &&
          !Number.isNaN(+price.minPrice);
    const checkSold = sold === "" ? "initial values" : !Number.isNaN(+sold);

    if (!checkPrice || !checkSold) {
      setCheckInput({ checkPrice: !checkPrice, checkSold: !checkSold });
      return false;
    }

    const x = arrProd.filter(prod => {
      const filterPrice =
        checkPrice === "initial values"
          ? true
          : +prod.price > +price.minPrice && +prod.price < +price.maxPrice;
      const filterSold =
        checkSold === "initial values" ? true : +sold >= +prod.sold;

      return filterPrice && filterSold;
    });
    setProcessingProd(x);
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <form onSubmit={FormSubmit}>
        {checkInput.checkPrice && (
          <div>{"Please provide a valid price range"}</div>
        )}
        {"Min"}
        <input
          type={"text"}
          name={"minPrice"}
          size={6}
          maxLength={10}
          value={price.minPrice}
          onChange={PriceMaxMin}
        />
        {"Max"}
        <input
          type={"text"}
          name={"maxPrice"}
          size={6}
          maxLength={10}
          value={price.maxPrice}
          onChange={PriceMaxMin}
        />
        {checkInput.checkSold && (
          <div>{"Please provide a valid price range"}</div>
        )}
        {"Sold"}
        <input
          type={"text"}
          name={"minPrice"}
          size={6}
          maxLength={10}
          value={sold}
          onChange={({ target: { value, name } }) => setSold(value)}
        />
        <input type="submit" title={"Submit price range"} value={"Go"} />
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: I assume you are referring to the 'is empty' check as being meaningless; the range check is still relevant, right? How about: `const x = checkPrice === "initial values" ? arrProd : arrProd.filter(prod => prod.price > +price.minPrice && +prod.price < +price.maxPrice && +sold >= +prod.sold);`

Comment: Your code is fine as is. I bet JIT will optimize the check away.

Comment: @Ruud Helderman     Don't think your example is correct,here is a small example of what can [happen](https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-easley-xk7ti);

Comment: @Dafang Cao You consider senseless checks correct?

Comment: @Will Jenkins What are you speaking about?

Comment: sorry, I was being unhelpful... I think this could do with a bit of a refactor is all. I think you could start by ensuring your inputs are only numbers so you can do away with the whole "initial values" thing. Then your numbers will be either undefined, in which case you should't filter, or defined, in which case you should.

Comment: I would also separate your two filtering operations into separate concerns. The logic of doing both in parallel is hard to understand and would be difficult to extend and maintain. You could even chain your two filtering operations and make the filtering functions dependent on the state of your inputs. i.e. they either filter or pass through.

Comment: @Will Jenkins I agree that it is necessary to separate the logic of checking inputs.But by the separation of the array check, I disagree..Can you give an example Maybe I misunderstand you.

Comment: @Squanchy I never suggested to remove the `isNaN` calls. My code sample is a replacement of your own `const x = ...;` statement. I duplicated your numeric comparisons. Notice these never get called if `checkPrice === "initial values"`. If my code sample suffers from string-typed comparisons, then so does yours.

Comment: @Ruud Helderman Can you show your example completely. To more accurately answer you.Thank you in advance.

Comment: JavaScript engine can figure out that `checkPrice === "initial values"` is a constant. So it will perform the check only once. If it's smart, the check won't even be full string comparison. Using `eval` is the worst you can do in this case, as it turns off optimization.

Comment: @DafangCao Hello.Can you inform me how you know about it ?Could you please, send me a link or something similar that can prove your words?Thank you.

Comment: See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/KuromiAK/d233322ebc1d3e5fb05cb7697b4d30dd).

Comment: @Dafang Cao But all this will not work here.[Take a look yourself.](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-banzai-p4h55) ;I just have to change the logic of if ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure after reading your question, but I assume you are referring to the way `checkPrice === "initial values"` and `checkSold === "initial values"` are repeatedly tested within this filter:

```
const x = arrProd.filter(prod => {
  const filterPrice =
    checkPrice === "initial values"
      ? true
      : +prod.price > +price.minPrice && +prod.price < +price.maxPrice;
  const filterSold =
    checkSold === "initial values" ? true : +sold >= +prod.sold;

  return filterPrice && filterSold;
});
```

Indeed, it should be enough to test that just once.
So let's move the entire test outside of the filter.

```
const x = arrProd.filter(
    checkPrice === "initial values"
        ? checkSold === "initial values"
            ? prod => true
            : prod => +sold >= +prod.sold
        : checkSold === "initial values"
            ? prod => +prod.price > +price.minPrice && +prod.price < +price.maxPrice
            : prod => +prod.price > +price.minPrice && +prod.price < +price.maxPrice && +sold >= +prod.sold
);
```

Notice we now have four separate predicates. There is code duplication between them. This can be eliminated by using named functions.

```
const acceptAny = prod => true;
const acceptIfPriceInRange = prod => +prod.price > +price.minPrice && +prod.price < +price.maxPrice;
const acceptIfSoldInRange = prod => +sold >= +prod.sold;
const acceptIfBothInRange = prod => acceptIfPriceInRange(prod) && acceptIfSoldInRange(prod);

const x = arrProd.filter(
    checkPrice === "initial values"
        ? checkSold === "initial values" ? acceptAny : acceptIfSoldInRange
        : checkSold === "initial values" ? acceptIfPriceInRange : acceptIfBothInRange
);
```

Full source file:

```
import React, { Fragment, useCallback, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const arrProd = [
  {
    price: "5.75",
    sold: "100"
  },
  {
    price: "2.36",
    sold: "15"
  },
  {
    price: "5.48",
    sold: "20"
  },
  {
    price: "4.49",
    sold: "200"
  },
  {
    price: "3.15",
    sold: "258"
  },
  {
    price: "9.99",
    sold: "479"
  },
  {
    price: "4.8",
    sold: "147"
  },
  {
    price: "8",
    sold: "951"
  },
  {
    price: "4.27",
    sold: "753"
  },
  {
    price: "2.46",
    sold: "852"
  },
  {
    price: "4.99",
    sold: "742"
  },
  {
    price: "3.49",
    sold: "10"
  },
  {
    price: "2",
    sold: "26"
  },
  {
    price: "3.83",
    sold: "39"
  },
  {
    price: "9.98",
    sold: "47"
  },
  {
    price: "6.77",
    sold: "96"
  }
];

function App() {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState({ maxPrice: "", minPrice: "" });
  const [sold, setSold] = useState("");
  const [processingProd, setProcessingProd] = useState([]);
  const [checkInput, setCheckInput] = useState({
    checkPrice: false,
    checkSold: false
  });

  const PriceMaxMin = useCallback(({ target: { value, name } }) => {
    name === "maxPrice"
      ? setPrice(({ minPrice }) => ({ maxPrice: value, minPrice }))
      : setPrice(({ maxPrice }) => ({ minPrice: value, maxPrice }));
  }, []);
  console.log(processingProd);
  const FormSubmit = event => {
    if (checkInput.checkPrice) setCheckInput({ checkPrice: false });
    const checkPrice =
      price.minPrice === "" && price.minPrice === ""
        ? "initial values"
        : +price.maxPrice >= +price.minPrice &&
          price.minPrice !== "" &&
          !Number.isNaN(+price.maxPrice) &&
          !Number.isNaN(+price.minPrice);
    const checkSold = sold === "" ? "initial values" : !Number.isNaN(+sold);

    if (!checkPrice || !checkSold) {
      setCheckInput({ checkPrice: !checkPrice, checkSold: !checkSold });
      return false;
    }

    const acceptAny = prod => true;
    const acceptIfPriceInRange = prod => +prod.price > +price.minPrice && +prod.price < +price.maxPrice;
    const acceptIfSoldInRange = prod => +sold >= +prod.sold;
    const acceptIfBothInRange = prod => acceptIfPriceInRange(prod) && acceptIfSoldInRange(prod);

    const x = arrProd.filter(
        checkPrice === "initial values"
            ? checkSold === "initial values" ? acceptAny : acceptIfSoldInRange
            : checkSold === "initial values" ? acceptIfPriceInRange : acceptIfBothInRange
    );

    setProcessingProd(x);
    event.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <form onSubmit={FormSubmit}>
        {checkInput.checkPrice && (
          <div>{"Please provide a valid price range"}</div>
        )}
        {"Min"}
        <input
          type={"text"}
          name={"minPrice"}
          size={6}
          maxLength={10}
          value={price.minPrice}
          onChange={PriceMaxMin}
        />
        {"Max"}
        <input
          type={"text"}
          name={"maxPrice"}
          size={6}
          maxLength={10}
          value={price.maxPrice}
          onChange={PriceMaxMin}
        />
        {checkInput.checkSold && (
          <div>{"Please provide a valid price range"}</div>
        )}
        {"Sold"}
        <input
          type={"text"}
          name={"minPrice"}
          size={6}
          maxLength={10}
          value={sold}
          onChange={({ target: { value, name } }) => setSold(value)}
        />
        <input type="submit" title={"Submit price range"} value={"Go"} />
      </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Disclaimer: I didn't test the complete code; I will leave that up to you.

Comment: Thank you for your option.plus 5 points from me.you only check checkPrice here.and if checkPrice !== "initial values"  checkSold === "initial values",In this case, an empty array will be returned.and if the opposite is not filtered + sold> = + prod.sold;if I write Min 1 Max 10 in the inputs and leave the input sold as empty, then I got an empty array. And if on the contrary, we get an unprocessed array.

Comment: I even have this [idea](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-night-hjrls) , but I don’t think it’s a good practice to use eval.

Comment: @Squanchy Apologies, I had completely overlooked `checkSold`. I have fixed my answer, I hope it matches your requirements. Please let me know if you find something wrong. And as pointed out by others, [do not ever use eval!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Do_not_ever_use_eval!)